# Git Hook - PHP Script - charset issue

Tags: php, git, encoding, locale, githooks

I'm developing a per-project based/portable Git Hooks library in PHP. Now a strange problem occured: Currently the `pre-push` hooks have a strange issue. File encoding is UTF8 w/o BOM, but still the output is the following on Win cmd and (MySys)Git/GNU Bash:

```
-------------------------
 Running PHP Mess Detector
Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼Ôû¼
 Ôö£ÔöÇ ÔêÜ dev/templates/php/bar.php
 Ôö£ÔöÇ ÔêÜ dev/templates/php/foo.php
--------------------------
 ÔÖÑ All files mess free.
--------------------------
```

[`Goto Source`](https://github.com/wecodemore/GitPHPHooksLibrary/issues/1)

The chars should be relatively save. The original (which works on `pre-commit` hooks) looks like the following:

```
--------------------------
 Running PHP Mess Detector
▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
 ├─ √ dev/templates/php/bar.php
 ├─ √ dev/templates/php/foo.php
--------------------------
 ♥ All files mess free.
--------------------------
```

Example files to reproduce the issue (easily removable from a test env), can be found in my [Git PHP Hooks](https://github.com/wecodemore/GitPHPHooks) repo and the hook script itself in the according [Git PHP Hooks Library](https://github.com/wecodemore/GitPHPHooksLibrary) repo. *Both available on Packagist with `wcm/git-php-hooks(-library)`*.

What could be causing a charset difference with the same files running on two different hooks?

#### Edit

To inspect the `locale` on the CLI, I used (the following non-logical PHP way to get the local by calling `setlocale()` with a `0` value - do *not* use `NULL` or an `''` empty string as this will actually *reset* it).

```
print_r( explode( ";", setlocale( LC_ALL, 0 ) ) );
```

Then I tried to set the locale with the `setlocale()` function, which seems to work on OSX and Linux distributions (NIX systems). I tried all `UTF` variations (rule of: first wins according to the docs), with `C` being the default (English).

```
setlocale( LC_ALL,
    "en_US.UTF-8",
    "en_US.UTF8",
    "en_US.utf-8",
    "en_US.utf8",
    "C"
);
```

But everything got ignored and I had `German_Austria.1252` as result.

Comment: I'd start from exploring the environment of both scripts: put a code snippet dumping all the environment variables and their values to a file in each script and then compare the results after running both hooks. Especially look for variables named `LANG`, and `LC_*` (`LC_MESSAGES` etc) -- more info [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html).

Comment: @kostix The problem stays even if I explicitly set `LANG/LANGUAGE/LC_ALL` to `en_US.UTF8` up front of the code directly in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that, for some reason (on Windows 7) there is no possibility to beyond the ASCII 128 chars table for a git hook.

Again: No explanation, just the fact that this is the supported range that works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

#### Not yet a solution, but setting the locale is possible on Windows

*Win 7 in my case.*

After reading on the Debian [SVN site for `setlocale.c`](http://svn.gna.org/svn/warmux/trunk/build/lib/intl/src/setlocale.c), I found out that aside from the [ISO 639-2](https://github.com/ISO639/2) and the ISO 3166, there's the Standard of

> (...) convert the names from the form with ISO 639 language code and ISO 3166 country code to the form with English names or with three-letter identifier.

*Win32* - all I say. Now I tried a last thing: Debugg

```
setlocale( LC_ALL,
    "en_US.UTF-8",
    "en_US.UTF8",
    "en_US.utf-8",
    "en_US.utf8",
    "C",
    // This works on Win(7):
    "ENU",
    "English_United States.1252"
);
```

It doesn't matter if you use the 3 char code or the full string. The result always is the full/long string.

> **Important**: Check your local string first, as this setting looks like it's a permanent change. At least I could remove the setting afterwards and then still had the same local returned by `setlocale( LC_ALL, 0 );`. You **do not** mess up a users system. Reset to original - keep your house clean.